# Can you check if a SKSpriteNode is indirectly connected to another?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm working on a game where the player moves around a space station, consisting of tiles (called parts, inheriting SKSpriteNode). One of these parts is the 'Source'.

Here is a helpful image.

[image: Here is a helpful image.]

In the game, asteroids may hit the space station, and cause tiles to be destroyed. When this happens, I need to check if all the tiles are still connected to the source. If they are not, they need to be removed from the station (can't have floating tiles!). Useful point: Each tile has a name, "T|Empty" or for the source, "T|Source". Also, the obtainConnectedTiles function just finds the tiles up, down, left, and right of the part.

**What I've tried**

```
func checkIfConnectedToSource(_ part: SpaceStationPart) -> Bool {
    var foundSource = false

    let splitArray1 = part.name?.components(separatedBy: "|")
    if splitArray1?[1] == "Source" {
        foundSource = true
    }

    while !foundSource {
        let connections = part.obtainConnectedTiles(scene: self)
        if connections.count != 0 {
            for i in 0..<connections.count {
                let splitArray = connections[i].name?.components(separatedBy: "|")
                if splitArray?[1] != "Source" {
                    if checkIfConnectedToSource(connections[i]) {
                        foundSource = true
                    }
                } else {
                    foundSource = true
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Connections was 0!")
        }
    }

    return foundSource
}
```

I tried this, but it threw "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the line when I find the components of the name, although I'm not sure why.

The tiles are also always in a grid, 100 points apart from each other.

So, the question boils down to: How can I check if an SKSpriteNode is connected to another SKSpriteNode, sometimes indirectly?

Comment: From your description, since you have a function that tells you whether there are tiles adjacent to a current tile, it seems like you could use an "A Star" or "A*" alogorithm to see if there is a continuous path from a given tile to the source tile. If not path is found, then that tile is disconnected.  (You will probably find an A* function useful in your game anyway, say, to allow enemies to pathfind towards the player when parts are destroyed.)

Comment: That is a good point, I will attempt to implement it into the code. (I agree, A* would be useful in other aspects of the game as well.)

Comment: cc thanks so much for that suggestion, the implementation is a success! Raywenderlich helped a lot.